# Why does the Date class in Java display a year after subtracting 1900 from it?

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

Since the Date class in Java was deprecated, I had quite less frequently been using it but when I used it, felt that it might sometimes irritate someone as it displays the current year after subtracting 1900 from it. What should the designers have actually felt and imposed such a mechanism while the **Calendar** class and it's subclass **GregorianCalendar** return the exact year that is being maintained by the system as follows?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Date d=new Date();
        System.out.println("Day : "+d.getDate()+" Month : "+d.getMonth()
        +" Year :  "+d.getYear());

        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Day : "+c.get(Calendar.DATE)+" Month :  
       "+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+" Year : "+c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
}
```

---

It displays the output something like the one shown below, the current day, month and year.

Day : 1 Month : 10 Year : 111

Day : 1 Month : 10 Year : 2011

---

What the designers might have though about displaying **111** rather than **2011**?

Comment: Considering it was deprecated in JDK1.1, they probably realized very quickly they made a mistake...

Comment: Well, we can't go back in time and look in their minds, but my guess is that it was just a mistake, nothing more. Java 1.1 was pre-Y2K, after all. Then again, even that explanation is dubious.

Comment: Just to be clear. [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is most certainly _not_ deprecated. Its methods that deal with date parts, ie. month, day, year, etc. are deprecated. But [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) still has many valid uses.

Comment: `getYear()` it's deprecated, but can be fixed by adding +1900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subtraction is just for the sort year field 'y'.  If you specify the long year field, 'Y' no subtraction occurs.

If you mean, why does the default toString use the short year format, I assume it was the most natural expression the java devs came up with for the average situation.  If you need to display a Date object with a different formatted date, consider using the SimpleDateFormatter class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.format(new Date());
```